# lauterbach "no default loading agent available" error when using data.load with option checkOnly or checkload

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to load a .s19 file to a microcontroller memory.In order to check whether the code has been loaded successfully I have tried using the following commands :-

1. `Data.LOAD.S3record <filename.s19>  <address range> /CHECKONLY`
2. `Data.LOAD.S3record <filename>.s19>   <address range> /CHECKLOAD`

Both commands fail with error "no default loading agent available". I have looked at this document https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/error.pdf and it says it's because  "There is no standard target agent for this core (or configuration) available". However,I don't understand what this means or how to go about.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem. I am using a tricore device and as of today for TriCore devices a target agent is not available from Lauterbach.so the CHECKONLY option (and other similar options requiring a target agent) is not available.